# How can i go to previous fragment when i am using navigation

Tags: android, kotlin

i am now currently in signupfragment and need to go to loginfragment which is my previous fragment  but its not working

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        Log.e("BackPressed","Onbackpressed")
      findNavController().popBackStack(R.id.signupfragment,false)

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter to [`popBackStack(R.id.signupfragment,false)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#popBackStack(int,%20boolean)) is `popUpToInclusive`:

> `popUpToInclusive`: boolean: Whether the given destination should also be popped.

If you use `popUpToInclusive` of `false`, you are saying "pop everything up to `R.id.signupfragment`, but **not `R.id.signupfragment`**.

Therefore, if you are at `R.id.signupfragment`, this correctly pops nothing (and returns false). You want to either 1) use `true` for `popUpToInclusive` or 2) use the version of `popBackStack()` that doesn't take any parameters, as this is the equivalent of popping just your current destination off the back stack:

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    Log.e("BackPressed","Onbackpressed")
    findNavController().popBackStack()
}
```

Of course, Navigation **already** sets up the back button to call `popBackStack()` when you hit the back button, so besides your extra logging, your call is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: So what does `popBackStack()` return? What does `findNavController().currentDestination` return?

Comment: popBackStack returns true and current destination is also changing to loginfragment but the signupfragment page is still on there

Comment: what about `findNavController().navigateUp()`?

Comment: findNavController().popBackStack()
            findNavController().popBackStack()
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.loginFragment)

Comment: i have to use this code popBackStack two times and then needed to navigate to R.id.loginfragment why is that

Comment: It sounds like you're calling `navigate()` from within a `LiveData` `observe` callback, which means you are popping back, then immediately going forward again because [LiveData is not for events](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it easily is by putting a test back button and coding it with.

```
testBackButton.setOnClickListener {
val intent = Intent(this, ActivityThatYouWantToGo::class.java)
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
startActivity(intent)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know its a good answer but its working

```
findNavController().popBackStack()
findNavController().popBackStack()  
findNavController().navigate(R.id.loginFragment)
```